# Issue with php shell_exec function

Tags: php, shell-exec

While executing `shell_exec` I am getting the given log. The log is not stopping and causing high server logs.

I have tried different version of php ( php 5.6, php 7.0, php 7.1) but no hopes .

**Any fix available for this ?**

> [24-Aug-2017 12:38:57] NOTICE: [pool www] child 112108 exited with
>   code 0 after 58.651699 seconds from start
>
> [24-Aug-2017 12:38:57] NOTICE: [pool www] child 112161 started
>   [24-Aug-2017 12:38:57] NOTICE: [pool www] child 112161 exited with
>   code 0 after 0.002603 seconds from start
>
> [24-Aug-2017 12:38:57] NOTICE: [pool www] child 112162 started
>   [24-Aug-2017 12:38:57] NOTICE: [pool www] child 112162 exited with
>   code 0 after 0.001959 seconds from start
>
> [24-Aug-2017 12:38:57] NOTICE: [pool www] child 112108 exited with
>   code 0 after 58.651699 seconds from start
>
> [24-Aug-2017 12:38:57] NOTICE: [pool www] child 112161 started
>   [24-Aug-2017 12:38:57] NOTICE: [pool www] child 112161 exited with
>   code 0 after 0.002603 seconds from start

Comment: What command are you executing? Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a short research, I've found [this Articel](https://serverfault.com/a/535795) which might help you. It should be enought to set the log_level in your `php-fpm.conf` from `notice` to `warning`. This will suppress this message.

The reason your processes are exiting and respawning is that you have set the pm.max_requests option in your php-fpm pool configuration file.

Comment: Links may rot and disappear. Please copy the relevant portion from the linked article into your answer, with edits to clarify how the OP can use that information to solve the problem.